# Array property in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

If I define a property for a component `MyComp1` like that

```
props: {
  display: {
    type: [Boolean, Array],
    validator: function (value) {
      return value === false && value !== true;
    },
    default: false,
  },
},
```

How can I use it in my component `MyComp2`?
I tried different syntax's

```
<MyComp1 display=[mobile, tablet]><MyComp1>
<MyComp1 display="['mobile', 'tablet']"><MyComp1>
<MyComp1 display="mobile,tablet"><MyComp1>
```

but none works. Which is the right syntax?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-an-Array

Comment: To pass a property use :display or v-bind:display not just 'display'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the colon before 'display'

```
<MyComp1 :display="['mobile', 'tablet']"><MyComp1>
```

instead of

```
<MyComp1 display="['mobile', 'tablet']"><MyComp1>
```